# Recovering bricked Pixel 2 with drained battery

Tags: charging, google, unbricking, google-pixel-2

Bit of a weird setup but I have a Pixel 2 phone with offline charging disabled.

Today I wanted to restore the factory image so I booted the phone into TWRP, wiped all the partitions. I then got distracted and the battery drained.

Because I have disabled offline charging the battery won't charge now that the phone is off and the phone won't boot because it doesn't have enough power to switch on.

I have tried starting the phone into recovery but it seems like there is not enough juice even for this. The red LED on top flashes a couple of times but the screen stays black.

Any ideas how I can recover?

One idea I had was to open the phone and put a charged battery from another pixel in it but this involves taking apart two phones which is a bit drastic.

Comment: Does it charge in fastboot mode?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get into the bootloader to try,

Comment: I have removed the battery from the pixel but I'm having trouble charging it because the battery voltage is 3.85v and all the standard lion/lipo chargers are configured for 3.7v. I have purchased another battery from eBay so I'm hoping it comes with a little bit of charge in it.

Comment: voltage is not the critical value, stable current is the important criterion. li-ion chargers are constant current sources https://makingcircuits.com/blog/how-to-charge-a-li-ion-battery-correctly-and-safely